# NeuralProphet Future regressor forecasting error

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, facebook-prophet

I am facing error while trying to forecast for 10 days using my neuralProphet model.
Normally in neuralProphet we forecast for next 10 days using:

```
future = m.make_future_dataframe(df, periods=10)
forecast = m.predict(future)
```

But I am using added regressor for traing the model:

```
from neuralprophet import NeuralProphet
m = NeuralProphet(
    yearly_seasonality=True,
    weekly_seasonality=False,
    daily_seasonality=False,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=1500,
    #learning_rate=auto,
)
m = m.add_future_regressor(name='Volume')
m = m.add_future_regressor(name='High')
m = m.add_future_regressor(name='Low')
m = m.add_future_regressor(name='Adj Close')
m = m.add_future_regressor(name='Open')
metrics = m.fit(data, freq="D")
```

forecasting next 10 days using the above code I am getting error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 1
----> 1 future = m.make_future_dataframe(data, periods=10)
      2 forecast = m.predict(future)

File E:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\neuralprophet\forecaster.py:1473, in NeuralProphet.make_future_dataframe(self, df, events_df, regressors_df, periods,n_historic_predictions)
   1471 df_future_dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
   1472 for df_name, df_i in df.groupby("ID"):
-> 1473     df_aux = self._make_future_dataframe(
   1474         df=df_i,
   1475         events_df=events_dict[df_name],
   1476         regressors_df=regressors_dict[df_name],
   1477         periods=periods,
   1478         n_historic_predictions=n_historic_predictions,
   1479     )
   1480     df_aux["ID"] = df_name
   1481     df_future_dataframe = pd.concat((df_future_dataframe, df_aux), ignore_index=True)

File E:\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\neuralprophet\forecaster.py:2908, in NeuralProphet._make_future_dataframe(self, df, events_df, regressors_df, periods, n_historic_predictions)
   2906 if self.config_regressors is not None and periods > 0:
   2907     if regressors_df is None:
-> 2908         raise ValueError("Future values of all user specified regressors not provided")
   2909     else:
   2910         for regressor in self.config_regressors.keys():

ValueError: Future values of all user specified regressors not provided
```

I tried reading the documentation also but no input on forecasting part : https://neuralprophet.com/new-tutorials/tutorial06.html

Answer (score 0):

there is a parameter in make_future_dataframe in neuralprophet that allows you to send a dataframe that contains future values of your regressors. You need to share that in the code, that's what the error says.

Comment: Do you have a code example or some documentation?